# Save a Variant Array of Bytes to a Parameterised Query

Tags: delphi, datasnap

In a TDataSetProvider.OnBeforeUpdate event handler of a ClientDataSet that contains a blob field, I want to assign the value of the `DeltaDS.Fields[i].NewValue` which happens of course to be a Variant Array of Bytes in this case for the blobField value - to a Query.Parameter for the `Update` statement eg `Update MyTable set myBlob = :myBlob where id = :id`

Clearly I'm making a mess of this.

What's the elegant way to do it? Thanks

```
    i := 0;
    while (i < DeltaDS.Fields.Count) do
    begin
       // not all the code, just the bit relevant to the question
       if (DeltaDS.Fields[i].DataType = TFieldType.ftBlob) then
       begin
         // field value is an Array of Byte
         // copy it first
         ab := DeltaDS.Fields[i].NewValue; // no error here
         if (Length(ab) * SizeOf(Char)) > 0 then
         begin
           Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
           try
             // write array of byte to stream
             Stream.WriteBuffer(ab[0], Length(ab) * SizeOf(Char));
             Stream.Position := 0; // rewind
             // load parameter from stream
             QryUpdate.Params.ParamByName(DeltaDS.Fields[i].FieldName).DataType := ftBlob;
             QryUpdate.Params.ParamByName(DeltaDS.Fields[i].FieldName).LoadFromStream(Stream);
           finally
             Stream.Free;
           end;
         end;
       end;
       Inc(i);
     end;
```

Comment: How is ab defined? Since you are dealing with bytes, the `SizeOf(Char)` entries seems suspicious...

Comment: `ab: Array of Byte;` Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I removed the `*Sizeof(Char)` from the 2 places where I do that. It appears my problems are resolved. Thanks

Comment: @nolaspeaker: You might consider using `TBytesStream` instead: `Stream := TBytesStream.Create(ab);`  Or better, use the `TParam.SetBlobData()` method: `QryUpdate.Params.ParamByName(DeltaDS.Fields[i].FieldName).SetBlobData(PByte(ab)^, Length(ab));` Or even the `TParam.AsBlob` property: `QryUpdate.Params.ParamByName(DeltaDS.Fields[i].FieldName).AsBlob := ab;`

Comment: Nice. Is the code (without the * SizeOf(Char) of course), "good" code though? It seems to do the job is the reason I'm asking.